# MS VS solution structure w.r.t. dependency injection unit tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection

Is the following MS VS solution structure and classes OK w.r.t. easy **unit tests** with **dependency injection**? Would your unit tests look similar?

If you call the calculations below over a WPF module, would you skip a test over the WPF since complicated, or would you still conisder testing it over the WPF module ?

Solution

1. ProjectWork

   Classes

   - IDev.cs

     ```
     public interface IDev
     {
       IToMeasure Measure();
     }
     public interface IToMeasure
     {
       double Value{ get; set; }
     }
     ```
   - CalculatingUnit.cs

     ```
     public class CalculatingUnit
     {
        int count = 0,
            maxMeasuredValues = 20;

        public double doMeasures(IDev myDevice)
        {
           // simulating measuring each Xms
           while (count < maxMeasuredValues ) 
           {
              return myDevice.Measure();
              count++;
           }
        }
     }
     ```
   - MyDevice.cs

     ```
     // non-deterministic (random) values
     public class MyDevice: IDev
     {
        private readonly MyRandom myRandomVar = new Random(0); 

        public IToMeasure Measure()
        {
           var meas = new Measure { Value = myRandomVar.NextRandom(2, 0.5) };
           return meas;
        }
     }
     ```
   - TestDevice.cs

     ```
     // deterministic values
     public class TestDevice : IDevice
     {
        int nrValues = 6;
        int gIdx = 0,
        gCount = 0;
        int[] testMeasures = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

        public IToMeasure Measure()
        {
           gIdx = gCount % nrValues;
           var meas = new Measure { Value = testMeasures[gIdx] };
           gCount++;

           return meas;
        }
     }
     ```
   - myDeviceWPF.cs // it seems complicated testing over WPF, so I dont test with it, would you also skip it ?

     ```
     class myDeviceViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
     {
       ...
     }
     ```
2. ProjectTest

   - myDevice_Test.cs

     ```
     [TestClass]
     public class myDevice_Test
     {
         [TestMethod]
         public void Test_doMeasures()
         {
             double actual = 1;
             double expected = 21.068;

             TestDevice myDevice;
             CalculatingUnit myCalculatingUnit;

             myDevice = new TestDevice();
             myCalculatingUnit = new CalculatingUnit();

             actual = myCalculatingUnit.doMeasures(myDevice );
             Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual , 0.001, "Wrong calculations");
         }
     }
     ```

Comment: in your MyDevice.cs file you are missing a closing `}` sure it was a typo but thought I would point it out

Comment: @Malachi : 10x. Yes, it was a typo. I just corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

First, some quality/stylistic comments:

This won't do what you want/isn't legal:

```
  while (count < maxMeasuredValues ) 
  {
     return myDevice.Measure();
     count++;
  }

// non-deterministic (random) values
private readonly MyRandom myRandomVar = new Random(0);
```

Random initialized with a fixed seed is deterministic.  Even with no seed (current time) it is technically deterministic, but that's pickier.  Also, I don't see how you are using `MyDevice` in the code sample.

```
    double actual = 1;
    double expected = 21.068;

    TestDevice myDevice;
    CalculatingUnit myCalculatingUnit;

    myDevice = new TestDevice();
    myCalculatingUnit = new CalculatingUnit();

    actual = myCalculatingUnit.doMeasures(myDevice );
```

In general, prefer to declare and assign a value at the same time.  This will make the functions shorter and more readable.

Other than that, the organization looks fine.